# How to directly extract fields of a nested dict using itemgetter in Python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm using python's itemgetter from the operator module.

This piece of code works perfectly fine:

```
from operator import itemgetter


example_dict = {
    "field1": 1,
    "field2": 2,
    "nestedDict": {
        "subfield1": 3
    }
}


field1, field2, nestedDict = itemgetter('field1', 'field2', 'nestedDict')(example_dict)

print(field1, field2, nestedDict)
```

Output:

```
1 2 {'subfield1': 3}
```

Is there any way that I could directly extract `subfield` from `nestedDict`?

Ideally something like this:

```
field1, field2, subfield1 = itemgetter('field1', 'field2', ('nestedDict', 'subfield1'))(example_dict)
```

I'm looking for a pythonic one-liner. I know how to solve this using a custom function or class, but I'd like to learn a better way to do it.

Comment: I don't think there is a Python builtin/stdlib thing for this.

Answer (score 1):

That's a use case for structural matching syntax with `match`/`case`:

```py
example = {"field1": 1, "field2": 2, "nestedDict": {"subfield1": 3}}

match example:
    case {
        "field1": field1,
        "field2": field2,
        "nestedDict": {"subfield1": subfield1},
    }:
        print(field1, field2, subfield1)

    case _:
        raise ValueError("unexpected example value")
```

Although the simple and obvious route is still readable:

```py
field1, field2, subfield1 = (
    example["field1"],
    example["field2"],
    example["nestedDict"]["subfield1"],
)
print(field1, field2, subfield1)
```

A nice external library for for working with nested data structures in a somewhat more declarative way is `glom`:

```py
field1, field2, subfield1 = (
    glom(example, spec)
    for spec in ["field1", "field2", "nestedDict.subfield1"]
)
print(field1, field2, subfield1)
```

Or a little bit more compact with the help of `functools.partial()`:

```py
from functools import partial

field1, field2, subfield1 = map(
    partial(glom, example), ["field1", "field2", "nestedDict.subfield1"]
)
print(field1, field2, subfield1)
```